# Get real connection from JNDI

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra, jndi

I've written my own jdbc driver. I've added some specific methods to the connection class. Now I have to use it with jdbc, but I cann't even cast connection object that I receive from datasource to my connection class. 

Can I use created methods somehow?

Comment: If you've written your own JDBC driver, how would you use it except with JDBC? How are you attempting to use it, and why are you trying to cast to your specific `Connection` type... that doesn't sound like `JDBC` to me.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I work with CassandraDB now. Cassandra JDBC driver doesn't support too much it's features so I've added needed stuff and now I wanna use it.

Comment: The issue is that you don't get "your" `Connection`. You get a container manager `Proxy` pf your `Connection`. You can only use JDBC methods with a JDBC driver.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch But I've found that since java 1.6 connection implements Wrapper interface so now it has method unwrap, that  "Returns an object that implements the given interface to allow access to non-standard methods, or standard methods not exposed by the proxy."